# Excel Power Query API Call, result returned to the current table with pre-specified column

Tags: excel, vba, powerquery

I am working with the [Proff API](https://api.proff.no/swagger/index.html?urls.primaryName=Proff%20API%201.1) to fetch the revenue of companies in Excel. Currently I am trying to make it work with Power Query, but I am open to VBA too.

The table is set up as such with the organization number (Org) as an input for the query, and the result should be outputted in the column "Revenue".

| Org | Revenue |
| --- | --- |
| 914742315 | x |
| 960514718 | x |

I have managed to create a working Power Query function that fetches the revenue from the API:
[image]

That, when called returns the revenue as number:
[image]

The result:
[image]

How can I implement this function in the table? The desired behavior should be that as soon as I type an organization number in the "Org" column, the function would fetch the revenue automatically in the "Revenue" column.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming your org is in column **Org** and your function is named **get_revenue**, Add column ... custom column...

```
 =get_revenue([Org])
```

Make sure your function actually uses the **org** variable to filter something.  First glance I don't even see that being referenced